# New error being thrown with tm package and dtm/wordclouds

Tags: r, tm, word-cloud

using R(3.2.5) and with the following packages loaded
'SnowballC', 'tm', 'NLP', 'RWeka', 'RTextTools',  'wordcloud', 'fpc'

```
carmenCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(feedback$Description))
carmenCorpus <- tm_map(carmenCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
carmenCorpus <- tm_map(carmenCorpus, removePunctuation)
carmenCorpus <- tm_map(carmenCorpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
carmenCorpus <- tm_map(carmenCorpus, stemDocument)
```

When I go to create a wordcloud i get the following error.  this is a new error, when the code was run several months ago there was no issue:

```
wordcloud(carmenCorpus, max.words = 100, random.order = FALSE)

# Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i, j, v, nrow = length(terms), ncol = length(corpus),  : 
#  'i, j' invalid
```

Please advise on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`wordcloud` cannot just take a corpus and magically churn out a wordcloud.

You have to do the hard work of converting it into a `TextDocumentMatrix` and then summing up the word frequencies:

```
# convert to TDM
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(carmenCorpus, control=list(stemming=True))

# calculate word frequencies
freqs = sort(rowSums(as.matrix(tdm)), decreasing=TRUE)

# plot wordcloud
wordcloud(names(freqs), freqs,
    max.words = 100,
    random.order = FALSE,
    # any other params you want to pass into wordcloud
    )
```